# Controller VS. List Controller (Error occurred while loading a Visualforce page)

Tags: controller, list

I want to use an extension to override the standard contoller of a custom object (DetailContact), which is the detail object in a master-detail relationship with Contact.

```
<apex:page standardController="DetailContact__c" extensions="myExtension">

public myExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
```

When loading the page, I got:

> Error occurred while loading a Visualforce page.

FYI, when I use:

```
<apex:page standardController="DetailContact__c" recordSetVar="ContactDetails" extensions="myExtension">

public myExtension(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller)
```

There is no error, but I don't understand why I would use recordSetVar parameter since I don't manipulate a list of DetailContact__c.

Moreover, I wand to use the standard save button, so I mustn't use a list controller.

Do you know a workaround ?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you pass any ID in the URL during the first scenario?

Comment: @SantanuHalder The page is called from a list button (which is located in the Contact detail page, in the DetailContact related list section). So the Url contains the id of the contact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to recreate your issue. Here are few possible reasons:

1. You can't bind a VF page with standard Controller to a List Button. Because list button passes a list of selected records when clicked, so the standard functionality would expect the VF page to catch those records in a StandardSetController(reason why your page works with StandardSetController).
2. Alternatively, keep your page with StandardController and you can use a URL in action of the list view button, like this- `URLFOR('apex/YourPageName');`

Like this

[image]

**Part 2:**
To have your contactId prepopulated, you can modify your extension constructor like this.

```
public MyExtension(ApexPages.StandardController std){
String cId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('contactid');
DetailContact__c dCon = (DetailContact__c)std.getRecord();
dCon.ContactId = cId;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried using point 2, but since the Contact Id is not available anymore, I used : {!URLFOR('/apex/PageName?contactid=Contact.Id')}. However, Contact.Id is not repaced by the Id, and remains as is...

Comment: I have updated my answer with part 2

Comment: Also, you should keep Contact.Id outside quotes in URLFOR. Like this - {!URLFOR('/apex/PageName?contactid='+Contact.Id)}